# How to use "all" and "any " for dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to python. I want to know how to `all` and `any` functions. Here is the dict I have

```
nodes = { "ip1": {"cpu": 10}, "ip2": {"cpu": 20}, "ip3": { "cpu": 30} }
```

I want to check all nodes cpu cusage is more that 50 or not. There are examples of `all` and `any` but they are very simple. How to know if all nodes are more than 50 or not using `all`?

Comment: Simply `all(v['cpu'] > 50 for v in nodes.values())`

Comment: @vaultah, Thanks a lot. Answer it. I'll accept.